# WSL2 seems to change network configuration or DISPLAY variable on start-up. Where can I see what happens?

Tags: command-line, display, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt, qt5

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04, and I have a problem trying to run Qt apps, currently discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428451/setting-up-the-display-environment-variable-on-wsl2-to-use-qt-software/1428856#1428856). The gist of it is that Qt calls a plugin, `xcb`, that tries to connect to a **display**. When I launch WSL2 from Windows GUI, **this display changes**.

From what I understand, WSL2 changes network parameters on startup, and I would like to know precisely what happens. Is there a config file I can find?

Specifically, this is what happens:

- From Windows `cmd`, I run `wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile`
- Ubuntu Bash opens in CMD window, I run `$ xeyes`. Xeyes opens, works well
- I start Ubuntu in a new window from a shortcut on my Desktop, to have the session on which I usuallly work
- `$ xeyes` returns `Error: Can't open display: :0`
- From Windows `cmd`, I close WSL2 with `wsl.exe --shutdown`
- From Windows `cmd` again, I restart WSL2: `wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile`
- Ubuntu Bash opens in CMD window, I run `$ xeyes`
- `$ xeyes` returns `Error: Can't open display: :0`

My conclusion from this is that a value was changed somewhere when I started WSL2 from the GUI. For instance, the DISPLAY variable, but if I print it before and after starting WSL2, it always prints `$DISPLAY: :0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access WSL2 Ubuntu's application on hosted machine's network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394866/access-wsl2-ubuntus-application-on-hosted-machines-network)

Comment: Hi, have you tried [GWSL](https://opticos.github.io/gwsl/) or/and [WSLG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps)?

Comment: *"I start Ubuntu Desktop from the shortcut"* - So that's something that didn't come up in the other question.  (1) What do you mean by this?  What "shortcut"?  How did you install Ubuntu Desktop under WSL?  As I mention in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986) Ubuntu Desktop / Gnome requires Systemd, which isn't well supported under WSL2.  (2) If the desktop is running, are you launching `xeyes` from the Terminal app inside the Desktop, or from the WSL terminal?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, good point. (1) I think WSL2 was installed using CMD, as in, `wsl --install`. Ubuntu 20.04 was installed by default, I think. When I run `wsl -v -l`, I only have Ubuntu and CentOS (installed but never run or used). The "shortcut" is precisely that, I usually launch my WSL2 session from a Windows shortcut, from the taskbar. I think I did a "pin to taskbar" when it it was running. (2) The first and last times (point 2 and 7 in my list), from the Terminal inside the Desktop. The second time (point 4 in my list), from the WSL terminal -- the thing that I would like to get working.

Comment: @rss.clement But do you really mean "Ubuntu Desktop", as in the GUI desktop with Gnome?  That's not installed with WSL with a `wsl --install`.  Did you use something like [Distrod](https://github.com/nullpo-head/wsl-distrod)?  Or do you mean something different by "Ubuntu Desktop"?

Comment: Nonono, no GUI on my Ubuntu, no Gnome, nothing. Just the default WSL install. I didn't use Distrod. Saying *Ubuntu Deskstop* was a big mistake, I meant *starting WSL from Windows* (opens Ubuntu bash in a new window), as opposed to starting WSL from the Terminal. Tried to clarify that in an edit