# ping ubuntu WSL Ping in the domain (Ubuntu and Windows10)

Tags: networking, server, dns, ping

On the PC PC-XXXX I have Windows 10 and in them through WSL2 I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.

In this Ubuntu I enter command which returns IP address

server@pc-xxxx:~$ hostname -I
173.30.161.185 -- this address is for example purposes just.

When on local PC PC-XXXX in Windows 10 I run cmd as an admin and eneter > ping 173.30.161.185 - the connection works.

When on distant PC in the same domain as PC-XXXX
with Windows 10 I run cmd as admin and enter > `ping 173.30.161.185` - the connection fails !!! How can I obtain the goal that from distant PC the connection works ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access WSL2 Ubuntu's application on hosted machine's network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394866/access-wsl2-ubuntus-application-on-hosted-machines-network)

Comment: the thing you're looking to do is actually a bit complicated, but it is doable. Instructions are in the link above